# How to forbid HTTP TRACE in lighttpd

Tags: http, lighttpd

In a recent PCIDSS scan at a client of mine, I got aware of *Web Server HTTP Trace/Track Method Support Cross-Site Tracing Vulnerability* (`CVE-2004-2320`, `CVE-2007-3008`). The proposed mitigation for Apache is this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_METHOD} ^TRACE
  RewriteRule .* - [F]
</IfModule>
```

How can I achieve the same in Lighttpd?

Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Supposedly lighttpd doesn't even implement TRACE. What is the real server being used?

Comment: Thanks for the info! There's several servers behind the web-facing proxy (pond), so I wasn't sure which server the vulnerability applied to. So if lighttpd doesn't implement TRACE, then I guess it was Apache ;)

Comment: Do you mean Pound? It shouldn't allow TRACE through by default, unless  it was reconfigured to do so. Time to update your question. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [src/keyvalue.c](http://git.lighttpd.net/lighttpd/lighttpd-1.x.git/tree/src/keyvalue.c?h=lighttpd-1.4.x#n15) for a list of HTTP methods recognized by lighttpd. The default configuration supports a subset of those.